# How can I bind static variable in wpf code behind?

Tags: wpf, binding, behind

I have static class 'MappingService'.

```
public  class MappingService : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    static readonly MappingService _Instance = new MappingService();
    public static MappingService Instance
    {
        get { return _Instance; }
    }

    public Efficiency Source { get; set; }
}
```

and create ComboBox in code behind.
I want to bind ItemsSource **MappingService.Instance.Source** in code behind.

```
comboBox.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("MappingService.Instance.Source") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
```

but I can't access MappingService.Instance.Source.

Pleas help me.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how you can bind:

```
var propertyPath = new PropertyPath("Source");
var binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding
{
     Path = propertyPath,
     Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
     Source = MappingService.Instance
};
BindingOperations.SetBinding(
    comboBox,
    System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty,
    binding);
```

Comment: thanks you, I had forgotten 'Source = MappingService.Instance'

Answer (score 1):

This is one simple way to do it.There might be better options than this depends on your deisgn. Try this

```
  public  class MappingService : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    static readonly MappingService _Instance = new MappingService();
    public static MappingService Instance
   {
    get { return _Instance; }
    }

    public MappingService BindingObject 
    {
    get { MappingService._Instance; }
    }
     public Efficiency Source { get; set; }
   }
```

And your xaml code.

```
  comboBox.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("BindingObject.Source") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
```

You just add your static reference inside your instance reference.

Comment: I can't understand point.  combobox.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("MappingService.Instance.Source") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay }); It is not work.